# How to use gulp-notify-growl?

Tags: growl, gulp-notify

I have remote-server(192.168.0.104) and work on laptop window computer(192.168.0.100) with win7.
I install growl for window.

## server

```
var growl = require('gulp-notify-growl');
var growlnotifier = growl({
    hostname: "192.168.0.100",
    password: "test"
}, "TestApp");

growlnotifier.onError({
    title: 'Compile Error',
    message: '<%= error.message %>
});
```

## laptop

tap security

```
checked  Require password for LAN apps
checked  Allow network notification
checked  Allow clients to subscribe to notifications

add "test" to Password Manager
```

'Compile Error' display in terminal.

```
[15:17:43] gulp-notify: [Compile Error] Cannot find module
```

but notifications not appear in window.

How to get notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using `gulp-notify` instead of `gulp-notify-growl`. With `gulp-notify-growl` the code you are using seems to be working. Find the correct module and install it again. Even though `gulp-notify-growl` is deprecated, it still works.

Note that when Growls picks the `gulp` app, you can configure the forwarding with the Growl UI, which is easier!